# How do you assign a UUID to posts/products/comments/reviews?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am currently building a system that syncs posts, products, comments and reviews to wordpress sites.

In my system, I am using UUIDs as ids for my objects.

What is the best way to attach UUIDs to Wordpress's Posts and Comments, WooCommerce's Products and Reviews?

Comment: you can store this identifier in a meta value of each object. product is a custom post type and a product review is a comment. look these functions : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_comment_meta

Comment: @mmm can you post that as an answer?